# SQL how to calculate age from birth date

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

is anyone know how to calculate AGE from birth of date?? using to_char?

```
  birth_date  
  ------------------  
  2/4/1972
  23/4/1999
  21/8/2001
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is `months_between()`:

```
trunc(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate year, month and day then here goes your solution.
(You can also choose to select year only. Then just ignore month and day column)

```
 create table temptable (birth_date date);

 insert into temptable values(date '1972-04-02');
 insert into temptable values(date '1999-04-23');
 insert into temptable values(date '2001-08-21');
```

Query:

```
 select trunc(months_between(sysdate,birth_date)/12) year,
            trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,birth_date),12)) month,
            trunc(sysdate-add_months(birth_date,trunc(months_between(sysdate,birth_date)/12)*12+trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,birth_date),12)))) day
     from temptable
```

Output:

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 49 | 2 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 | 11 |
| 19 | 9 | 13 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b89c487403e8a506ec9b031dcc56ca7e)*